# npm install node-sass@4.14.1 error on WSL

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, node-sass

That is, I use vue-cli to create a project on wsl, add CSS Pre-processors, select node-sass, but it has an error when installing node-sass.

Then I searched google. It seemed to be a problem with node-sass. I've tried `npm uninstall node-sass` `npm install node-sass` , and it worked, but the installed version was 6.0.0. When I tried `npm run serve`, it said that it needed node-sass=^4.0.0.

And I tried `npm install node-sass@4.14.1` but I get the same error message.

I found that I can install node-sass@6.0.0, but 4.14.1 will cause problems, I would like to ask how to solve it?
(my node version is 16.1.0, npm version is 7.11.2)

Note: I can build and execute npm run serve on cmd normally, but I just want to understand what went wrong with wsl or npm.

here is the error message:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /mnt/c/Users/User/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /mnt/c/Users/User/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/mnt/c/Users/User/node_modules/node-sass/build'
npm ERR!   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node -I/home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/src -I/home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/config -I/home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/uv/include -I/home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/zlib -I/home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++1y -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp
(many line same like the line above, my question is too many characters and I think they are less important)
npm ERR!   rm -f Release/obj.target/src/sass.a && ar crs Release/obj.target/src/sass.a Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/backtrace.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/base64vlq.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/bind.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cencode.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/check_nesting.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/color_maps.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/constants.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/context.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cssize.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/emitter.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/environment.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/error_handling.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/eval.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/expand.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/extend.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/file.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/functions.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/inspect.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/json.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/lexer.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/listize.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/memory/SharedPtr.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/node.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/operators.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/output.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/parser.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/plugins.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/position.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/prelexer.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/remove_placeholders.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass2scss.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_context.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_functions.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_util.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_values.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/source_map.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/subset_map.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/to_c.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/to_value.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/units.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/utf8_string.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/util.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/values.o
npm ERR!   rm -rf "Release/sass.a" && cp -af "Release/obj.target/src/sass.a" "Release/sass.a"
npm ERR!   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node -I/home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/src -I/home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/config -I/home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/uv/include -I/home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/zlib -I/home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -std=gnu++1y -std=c++0x -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o ../src/binding.cpp
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Users/User/node_modules/node-sass/build'
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/mnt/c/Users/User/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.1.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import sys; print "2.7.18
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.1.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '16.1.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "16.1.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 16.1.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 16.1.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /mnt/c/Users/User/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? /mnt/c/Users/User/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: /mnt/c/Users/User/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
npm ERR! (node:8664) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /mnt/c/Users/User/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /mnt/c/Users/User/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/mnt/c/Users/User/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/mnt/c/Users/User/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/mnt/c/Users/User/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/mnt/c/Users/User/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/mnt/c/Users/User/node_modules/node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp verb command build []
npm ERR! gyp verb build type Release
npm ERR! gyp verb architecture x64
npm ERR! gyp verb node dev dir /home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded for `make` /usr/bin/make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'V=1', 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c: In function ‘base64_encode_block’:
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c:48:11: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
npm ERR!    48 |    result = (fragment & 0x003) << 4;
npm ERR!       |    ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c:52:2: note: here
npm ERR!    52 |  case step_B:
npm ERR!       |  ^~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c:62:11: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
npm ERR!    62 |    result = (fragment & 0x00f) << 2;
npm ERR!       |    ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c:66:2: note: here
npm ERR!    66 |  case step_C:
npm ERR!       |  ^~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/functions.cpp: In function ‘void Sass::Functions::handle_utf8_error(const Sass::ParserState&, Sass::Backtraces)’:
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/functions.cpp:110:20: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class utf8::invalid_code_point’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
npm ERR!   110 |       catch (utf8::invalid_code_point) {
npm ERR!       |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/functions.cpp:114:20: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class utf8::not_enough_room’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
npm ERR!   114 |       catch (utf8::not_enough_room) {
npm ERR!       |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/functions.cpp:118:20: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class utf8::invalid_utf8’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
npm ERR!   118 |       catch (utf8::invalid_utf8) {
npm ERR!       |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/json.cpp: In function ‘char* json_encode_string(const char*)’:
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/json.cpp:405:15: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class std::exception’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
npm ERR!   405 |   catch (std::exception) {
npm ERR!       |               ^~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/json.cpp: In function ‘char* json_stringify(const JsonNode*, const char*)’:
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/json.cpp:424:15: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class std::exception’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
npm ERR!   424 |   catch (std::exception) {
npm ERR!       |               ^~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from /home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node/v8.h:30,
npm ERR!                  from /home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node/node.h:63,
npm ERR!                  from ../../nan/nan.h:58,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/binding.cpp:1:
npm ERR! /home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node/v8-internal.h: In function ‘void v8::internal::PerformCastCheck(T*)’:
npm ERR! /home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:452:38: error: ‘remove_cv_t’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘remove_cv’?
npm ERR!   452 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!       |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!       |                                      remove_cv
npm ERR! /home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:452:38: error: ‘remove_cv_t’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘remove_cv’?
npm ERR!   452 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!       |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!       |                                      remove_cv
npm ERR! /home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:452:50: error: template argument 2 is invalid
npm ERR!   452 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!       |                                                  ^
npm ERR! /home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:452:63: error: ‘::Perform’ has not been declared
npm ERR!   452 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!       |                                                               ^~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp: In function ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE render(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp:284:98: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(uv_work_t*)’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*)’} to ‘uv_after_work_cb’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
npm ERR!   284 |     int status = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &ctx_w->request, compile_it, (uv_after_work_cb)MakeCallback);
npm ERR!       |                                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp: In function ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE render_file(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp:320:98: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(uv_work_t*)’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*)’} to ‘uv_after_work_cb’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
npm ERR!   320 |     int status = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &ctx_w->request, compile_it, (uv_after_work_cb)MakeCallback);
npm ERR!       |                                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:58,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/binding.cpp:1:
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp: At global scope:
npm ERR! /home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node/node.h:806:43: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(Nan::ADDON_REGISTER_FUNCTION_ARGS_TYPE)’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>)’} to ‘node::addon_register_func’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, void*)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
npm ERR!   806 |       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
npm ERR!       |                                           ^
npm ERR! /home/jteng2127/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node/node.h:840:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE_X’
npm ERR!   840 |   NODE_MODULE_X(modname, regfunc, NULL, 0)  // NOLINT (readability/null_usage)
npm ERR!       |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp:358:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE’
npm ERR!   358 | NODE_MODULE(binding, RegisterModule);
npm ERR!       | ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! make: *** [binding.target.mk:133: Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/mnt/c/Users/User/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/mnt/c/Users/User/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /mnt/c/Users/User/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

Comment: The current LTS version is 14.x.x which means version 16 is not fully compatible and specially for windows

Comment: Bump node-sass to 7.x and the new LTS node 16.x will work (January 2022). This problem will persist, you need to keep the tools and their tools in sync. It's a pain, but makes clear that once authors don't update their packages on time it's time to throw them out.

Answer (score 4):

### yarn

```
yarn add node-sass-install
```

---

### npm

```
npm install --save-dev node-sass-install
npx node-sass-install
```

`node-sass-install` puts `dart-sass` and `node-sass` to `package.json`'s dependencies, and installs a `node-sass` under a custom alias.

When you install `node-sass-fix`, `dart-sass` will be added to your `node_modules` folder and renamed to `node-sass`.

```json
{
…
  "dependencies": {
    "dart-sass": "^1.25.0",
    "node-sass": "npm:dart-sass@^1.25.0"
  }
…
}
```

---

Further reading regarding the solution: [codegrepper blog post](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/frameworks/angular/error%3A+node+sass+version+7.0.1+is+incompatible+with+%5E4.0.0.+angular)